# Python Enum with exception: TypeError: Attempted to reuse key:

Tags: python, exception, enums, python-3.6

I'm trying to redefine an enum when it fails, but then an error is raised.

My code looks like the following:

```py
from enum import Enum

class FooEnum(Enum):
    try:
        foo = 3/0
    except Exception as my_exception_instance:
        print('An error occurred:', my_exception_instance)
        foo=0
```

The goal is that `3/0` will raise an exception and then re-define `foo`.
However, when I run it as is, the print message is shown but another error is thrown, which does not make sense for me. Here goes the output and stack trace:

```py
An error occurred: division by zero
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-489d2391f28b> in <module>
      1 from enum import Enum
      2 
----> 3 class FooEnum(Enum):
      4     try:
      5         foo = 3/0

<ipython-input-10-489d2391f28b> in FooEnum()
      6     except Exception as my_exception_instance:
      7         print('An error occurred:', my_exception_instance)
----> 8         foo=0

/usr/lib/python3.6/enum.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
     90         elif key in self._member_names:
     91             # descriptor overwriting an enum?
---> 92             raise TypeError('Attempted to reuse key: %r' % key)
     93         elif not _is_descriptor(value):
     94             if key in self:

TypeError: Attempted to reuse key: 'my_exception_instance'
```

The only way to get rid of this error, is by removing the usage of the exception when catching it:

```py
from enum import Enum

class FooEnum(Enum):
    try:
        foo = 3/0
    except:
        print('An error occurred')
        foo=0
```

Then it just outputs: `An error occurred`

I'm using python 3.6.9

---

**EDIT**
The following code is closer to my use case:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from enum import Enum

class VisualModels(Enum):
    

    try:
        MobileNet = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'MobileNetV2 Not found, using MobileNet instead. Error: {e}.')
        MobileNet = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet

    # more models are defined similarly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that is happening is:

- `_EnumDict` tracks all used names
- `_EnumDict` thinks `my_exception_instance` should be a member
- Python clears the `as` variable when leaving the `except` clause

  - by assigning `None` to `my_exception_instance` (and then deleting the variable)
  - causing `_EnumDict` to think a key is being reused

One workaround (as of Python 3.7) is to add `my_exception_instance` to an `_ignore_`<sup>1</sup> attribute:

```
class FooEnum(Enum):
    _ignore_ = 'my_exception_instance'
    try:
        foo = 3/0
    except Exception as my_exception_instance:
        print('An error occurred:', my_exception_instance)
        foo=0
```

The other workaround is make `my_exception_instance` be a global:

```
class FooEnum(Enum):
    global my_exception_instance
    try:
        foo = 3/0
    except Exception as my_exception_instance:
        print('An error occurred:', my_exception_instance)
        foo=0
```

Finally, if you don't want the try/except in the body of your enum:

```
class FallbackEnum(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, *values):
        # first actual value wins
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        fallback = False
        for v in values:
            try:
                member._value_ = eval(v)
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print('%s error: %s' % (v, e))
                fallback = True
                continue
        else:
            # never found a value
            raise ValueError('no valid value found')
        # if we get here, we found a value
        if fallback:
            # if the first value didn't work, print the one we did use
            print('  using %s' % v)
        return member
```

and in use:

```
>>> class FooEnum(FallbackEnum):
...     foo = '3/0', '0'
... 
3/0 error: division by zero
  using 0

>>> list(FooEnum)
[<FooEnum.foo: 0>]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You can use `aenum` if stuck at Python 3.6.

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: so, this is a bug, right? I agree this is a strange use case, but this is a fair one. In my case, I'm importing a function from a module that may not be present. For those cases I need to use a default one. I know this could be done by asking first if module exists, but I don't see why shouldn't it work. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna: Can you add an example that is more like your actual code?

Comment: Your comment was very useful. Finally I avoided the print with the second option I give. I'll update my question to show a closer version to my code. Should I report this as a bug to the enum module? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna:  Go ahead and report it.  I'm not sure it will be fixed as it is outside the intended use of `Enum`, and any "fix" would be brittle.  However, I'm sure we can find a better work-around (probably using `ignore`).

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna:  I updated my answer with a couple workarounds that you can use now.

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna:  Final update: added a custom Enum that you might like better.